# AutoHotkey: arrays & objects scope

Tags: arrays, object, scope, autohotkey

I'm trying to understand the scope of arrays and objects in AHK. I need to define one and edit and read values from it using different hotkeys. This works:

```
^!Numpad1::
obj := {}
obj["a"] := "val"
Return

^!Numpad2::
MsgBox, % obj["a"] ; This correctly displays "val"
Return
```

But I don't want to re-initialise the object every time. Since it needs to act as a "memory" to keep info between hotkey presses, I'd like to initialise it once when the script is first loaded. However, if I move the initialisation outside, the assignment doesn't work:

```
obj := {}

^!Numpad1::
obj["a"] := "val"
Return

^!Numpad2::
MsgBox, % obj["a"] ; This now displays nothing
Return
```

Exactly the same behaviour with arrays. I've tried searching for info about the scope but all pieces of doc mention functions, which I'm not using. What am I missing?

Comment: You are running the Numpad1 hotkey before the Numpad2 hotkey, right? I just tried running both of the scripts and they appear to be functioning identically. Can you provide some more information regarding either your script itself or the procedure that you are using in order to validate whether or not the script is functioning properly?

Comment: This probably isn't the full script and your variable definition `obj := {}` is outside of the [auto-execute section](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto), so the code never actually runs.

Comment: @0x464e I realised that was indeed the issue, the script was just what I posted but I was running it by including it in a master script that runs a bunch, so the object was never initialising. I fixed with a check for intialisation:

`if (!IsObject(obj)) {obj := {}}`